# Idiomatically Handling form.errors In Django

Tags: django

I'm just starting with Django and I'm to the point where I'm validating form input. I have some code that basically looks like this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = RepairerForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():

        ...
    else:
        return HttpResponse(form.errors)
```

To trigger the else clause I enter a non-valid email address into an EmailField field.

My problem is that I don't know the "proper" way of telling the user that they entered invalid. `form.errors` is a dictionary, so I guess I could convert that into a nicely-formatted list and then process that in my template, but it sounds kludgy. Also, I haven't been able to find any tutorials that actually tell you what to do with `form.errors`. They all more or less pretend that it doesn't exist.

I could spend a while trying to roll my own solution, but I've learned with Django that almost everything have a nice, clean solution. Am I wrong this time, or should I just convert my errors into a string list and loop over that in my template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you say that no documentation tells to what to do with form errors. The standard [form overview docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/#the-view) show you exactly what to do.

The point is, just showing the error messages by themselves is useless; you should re-display the form with both the error messages and the data the user entered, so the user can correct what they need to and then resubmit.

If you display the form with just `{{ form.as_p }}`, each field will automatically be displayed with its errors; otherwise you can display each one individually with `{{ form.my_field.errors }}` or all in one go with `{{ form.errors }}`. Again, this is explained in full on that same [documentation page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/#rendering-form-error-messages).

Comment: Thanks! The 1.7 docs seem to have a bit more on the subject than the 1.4 docs that I am using. That definitely makes it more clear. My problem wasn't that I didn't read that document, it's that they don't seem to have a path for POST request in the form handler method that don't pass the "is_valid" test. That path is ignored in the 1.4 doc and every other tutorial I've found. Now I'm just redirecting to the calling page again and passing the form object and you're right, that does just work. Thanks again!

Comment: The point is that it when is_valid is False it just falls through to the render at the end, which re-displays the template with the invalid form object.